# The current request does not have a file in a key named `emblem`

Tags: laravel

When trying to register a variation of motorcycle without sending emblem and / or highlighted image causes failure, please correct.

The same does not occur when during the editing step.

```
protected function syncImage(Request $request, Model $model){
    $model->addMediaFromRequest(MediaCollectionDictionary::EMBLEM)
        ->toMediaCollection(MediaCollectionDictionary::EMBLEM);

    $model->addMediaFromRequest(MediaCollectionDictionary::FEATURED_IMAGE)
        ->toMediaCollection(MediaCollectionDictionary::FEATURED_IMAGE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: you sened `form post` when click??

Comment: No, :(
`GET|HEAD  | brand/{brand}/motorcycle/{motorcycle}/variations/create`

Comment: Can you run `dd($request->hasFile('embem') ? 'Yes' : 'No');` before `addMediaFromRequest ` call and share the result with us? It looks like the request is missing the `embem` file.

Comment: Placing files or not the test always returns me the answer "No"

Comment: when I use the edit, I passing the empty image field it does not show me that error.

Comment: if you are trying to submit images as input file please check if the enctype attribute is  "multipart/form-data" `<form action="{{url("brand/{brand}/motorcycle/{motorcycle}/variations/create")}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` in form attributes